# get the HTTP status server

Tags: android, http, post

Hi I am developing an android application, I like to create a class to get the HTTP status before send the data to the server with HTTP Post.

Have any form to get the HTTP status of this server?

I read to get the 200 code is the server is running and another code no

Thanks.

Resolved the timeout is very long, My solution is:

```
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10000);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```

and then:
                HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(server);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

Comment: do you want to know if the server is up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get Response code if you are using HttpUrlConnection :
when server is not running

```
  int status = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
  Log.i("", "Status : " + status);
```

And here is if you are using HttpClient :

```
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 Log.w("Response ","Status line : "+ response.getStatusLine().toString());
```

Comment: Is the same, when server is not running the application close

Comment: you can add to catch the exception, and that would result in no connection. sample below   

catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to server", e);

Comment: Kindly do this on a aysctask else android will throw NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: I answer to you in the fisrt post, I can't paste the code here

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(myUri);
HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

Comment: Your response is valid but I have a problem when the server is not running, you have any idea to repair it?